# Why so much criticism around Spark Streaming micro-batch (when using kafka as source)?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

Since any Kafka Consumer is in reality consuming in batches, why there is so much criticism around Spark Streaming micro-batch (when using Kafka as his source), for example, in comparison to Kafka Streams (which markets itself as real streaming)?

I mean: a lot of criticism hover on Spark Streaming micro-batch architecture. And, normally, people say that Kafka Streams is a real 'real-time' tool, since it processes events one-by-one.

It does process events one by one, but, from my understanding, it uses (as almost every other library/framework) the Consumer API. The Consumer API polls from topics in batches in order to reduce network burden (the interval is configurable). Therefore, the Consumer will do something like:

```java
while (true) {
        ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(100);

        ///// PROCESS A **BATCH** OF RECORDS
        for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {

            ///// PROCESS **ONE-BY-ONE**
        }
}
```

So, although it is right to say that Spark:

1. maybe has higher latency due to its micro-batch minimum interval that limits latency to at best 100 ms (see Spark Structured Streaming DOCs);
2. processes records in groups (either as DStreams of RDDs or as DataFrames in Structured Streaming).

But:

1. One can process records one-by-one in Spark - just loop though RDDs/Rows
2. **Kafka Streams in reality polls batches of records**, but processes them one-by-one, since it implements the Consumer API under-the-hoods.

Just to make clear, I am not questioning from a 'fan-side' (and therefore, being it an opinion question), just the opposite, I am really trying to understand it technically in order to understand the semantics in the streaming ecosystem.

Appreciate every piece of information in this matter.

Comment: Any Kafka clients pull in batches, yes. How is this a Spark question? Or Kafka Streams question?

Comment: This is a question aiming to **compare streaming semantics between streaming tools when a kafka topic is the source**. The **main focus is to understand the criticism to Spark micro batch when kafka is the source**. I used Kafka Streams for comparison, but I could use Storm or Flink as well.

Comment: @OneCricketeer, I change it a lit bit to add clarification. Is the question clear now? Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you can link to sources of "criticism"? Personally, my critique with Spark exists for Storm/Flink as well - requires too much extra dependencies if you only need to use the streaming features

Comment: Almost every single post about stream processing compares spark vs others frameworks/libs cites the micro-batch architecture. And even those frameworks market themselves as real streaming, since they do not micro batch, but process one by one. See for example, how kafka streams market themselves https://www.confluent.io/blog/introducing-kafka-streams-stream-processing-made-simple/?_ga=2.181210471.118615723.1609363160-166019130.1605037049&_gac=1.84077931.1609363166.CjwKCAiA57D_BRAZEiwAZcfCxcXiTLP2wcw1SLf01YNZpYoxukUOu1E0qAUG0Q-Aw80hZSA8n6F25RoCPewQAvD_BwE.

Comment: And here they say "Microbatch processing is useful when we need very fresh data, but not necessarily real-time" – https://www.upsolver.com/blog/batch-stream-a-cheat-sheet.

Comment: @OneCricketeer, can you also please elaborate about your personal criticism when you said: "requires too much extra dependencies if you only need to use the streaming features"?

Comment: The Confluent blog was written by the creator of Kafka, CEO of Confluent, and before the Spark Structured Streaming micro-batch semantics were mainstream (i.e. he has something to sell, and is biased). I think the main takeaway here is the definition of "real time" is vague - you need to deploy the app, it needs to start, needs to establish network connectivity, deserialize data, only then can it process it. For anything other than Kafka Streams, you are required to use an orchestrator like YARN, Mesos, etc. for scalability. That's what I meant by more dependencies

Comment: In your second link - _In practice, there is little difference between micro-batching and stream processing, and the terms would often be used interchangeably in data architecture descriptions and software platform descriptions_

Comment: The major problem with Spark micro-batching is that it is not smart enough to detect 0 size batches. If there's no data in Kafka (because you are caught up), it still continues to schedule 0 size batches vs skipping the scheduling it altogether. Each 0 size batch takes some millis to process leading to a huge lag to process actual data because there are tons them. I don't know if Spark ever came up with a solution to that scheduling problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

DISCLAIMER: I had involved in Apache Storm (which is known to be a streaming framework processing "record-by-record", though there's trident API as well), and now involving in Apache Spark ("micro-batch").

The one of major concerns in streaming technology has been "throughput vs latency". In latency perspective, "record-by-record" processing is clearly a winner, but the cost of "doing everything one by one" is significant and every minor thing becomes a huge overhead. (Consider the system aims to process a million records per second, then any additional overhead on processing gets multiplexed by a million.) Actually, there was opposite criticism as well, bad throughput on "read-by-record" compared to the "micro-batch". To address this, streaming frameworks add batching in their "internal" logic but in a way to less hurting latency. (like configuring the size of batch, and timeout to force flush the batch)

I think the major difference between the twos is that whether the tasks are running "continuously" and they're composing a "pipeline".

In streaming frameworks do "record-by-record", when the application is launched, all necessary tasks are physically planned and launched altogether and they never terminate unless application is terminated. Source tasks continuously push the records to the downstream tasks, and downstream tasks process them and push to next downstream. This is done in pipeline manner. Source won't stop pushing the records unless there's no records to push. (There're backpressure and distributed checkpoint, but let's put aside of the details and focus on the concept.)

In streaming frameworks do "micro-batch", they have to decide the boundary of "batch" for each micro-batch. In Spark, the planning (e.g. how many records this batch will read from source and process) is normally done by driver side and tasks are physically planned based on the decided batch. This approach gives end users a major homework - what is the "appropriate" size of batch to achieve the throughput/latency they're targeting. Too small batch leads bad throughput, as planning a batch requires non-trivial cost (heavily depending on the sources). Too huge batch leads bad latency. In addition, the concept of "stage" is appropriate to the batch workload (I see Flink is adopting the stage in their batch workload) and not ideal for streaming workload, because this means some tasks should wait for the "completion" of other tasks, no pipeline.

For sure, I don't think such criticism means micro-batch is "unusable". Do you really need to bother the latency when your actual workload can tolerate minutes (or even tens of minutes) of latency? Probably no. You'll want to concern about the cost of learning curve (most likely Spark only vs Spark & other, but Kafka stream only or Flink only is possible for sure.) and maintenance instead. In addition, if you have a workload which requires aggregation (probably with windowing), the restriction of latency from the framework is less important, as you'll probably set your window size to minutes/hours.

Micro-batch has upside as well - if there's a huge idle, the resources running idle tasks are wasted, which applies to "record-to-record" streaming frameworks. It also allows to do batch operations for the specific micro-batch which aren't possible on streaming. (Though you should keep in mind it only applies to "current" batch.)

I think there's no silver bullet - Spark has been leading the "batch workload" as it's originated to deal with problems of MapReduce, hence the overall architecture is optimized to the batch workload. Other streaming frameworks start from "streaming native", hence should have advantage on streaming workload, but less optimal on batch workload. Unified batch and streaming is a new trend, and at some time a (or a couple of) framework may provide optimal performance on both workloads, but I'm not sure now is the time.

EDIT: If your workload targets "end-to-end exactly once", the latency is bound to the checkpoint interval even for "record-by-record" streaming frameworks. The records between checkpoint compose a sort of batch, so checkpoint interval would be a new major homework for you.

EDIT2:

Q1) Why windows aggregations would make me bother less about latency? Maybe one really wants to update the stateful operation quickly enough.

The output latency between micro-batch and record-by-record won't be significant (even the micro-batch could also achieve the sub-second latency in some extreme cases) compared to the delay brought by the nature of windowing.

But yes, I'm assuming the case the emit happens only when window gets expired ("append" mode in Structured Streaming). If you'd like to emit all the updates whenever there's change in window then yes, there would be still difference on the latency perspective.

Q2) Why the semantics are important in this trade-off? Sounds like it is related, for example, to Kafka-Streams reducing commit-interval when exactly-once is configured. Maybe you mean that checkpointing possibly one-by-one would increase overhead and then impact latency, in order to obtain better semantics?

I don't know the details about Kafka stream, so my explanation won't be based on how Kafka stream works. That would be your homework.

If you read through my answer correctly, you've also agreed that streaming frameworks won't do the checkpoint per record - the overhead would be significant. That said, records between the two checkpoints would be the same group (sort of a batch) which have to be reprocessed when the failure happens.

If stateful exactly once (stateful operation is exactly once, but the output is at-least once) is enough for your application, your application can just write the output to the sink and commit immediately so that readers of the output can read them immediately. Latency won't be affected by the checkpoint interval.

Btw, there're two ways to achieve end-to-end exactly once (especially the sink side):

1. supports idempotent updates
2. supports transactional updates

The case 1) writes the outputs immediately so won't affect latency through the semantic (similar with at-least once), but the storage should be able to handle upsert, and the "partial write" is seen when the failure happens so your reader applications should tolerate it.

The case 2) writes the outputs but not commits them until the checkpoint is happening. The streaming frameworks will try to ensure that the output is committed and exposed only when the checkpoint succeeds and there's no failure in the group. There're various approaches to make the distributed writes be transactional (2PC, coordinator does "atomic rename", coordinator writes the list of the files tasks wrote, etc.), but in any way the reader can't see the partial write till the commit happens so checkpoint interval would greatly contribute the output latency.

Q3) This doesn't necessarily address the point about the batch of records that Kafka clients poll.

My answer explains the general concept which is also applied even the case of source which provides a batch of records in a poll request.

- Record-by-record: source continuously fetches the records and sends to the downstream operators. Source wouldn't need to wait for the completion of downstream operators on previous records. In recent streaming frameworks, non-shuffle operators would have handled altogether in a task - for such case, the downstream operator here technically means that there's a downstream operator requires "shuffle".
- Micro-batch: the engine plans the new micro-batch (the offset range of the source, etc.) and launch tasks for the micro batch. In each micro batch, it behaves similar with the batch processing.

Comment: I really appreciate your thorough answer. Made me better understand the trade-off.
Could you please elaborate on two points: 
1) Why windows aggregations would make me bother less about latency? Maybe one really wants to update the stateful operation quickly enough.
2) Why the semantics are important in this trade-off? Sounds like it is related, for example, to Kafka-Streams reducing commit-interval when exactly-once is configured. Maybe you mean that checkpointing possibly one-by-one would increase overhead and then impact latency, in order to obtain better semantics?

Comment: This doesn't necessarily address the point about the batch of records that Kafka clients poll.

Comment: I'll update my answer, as these don't seem to be something I could explain within the short text form.

Comment: I've updated my answer as EDIT2. I'm not 100% sure about the meaning "This doesn't necessarily address the point about the batch of records that Kafka clients poll." so please elaborate a bit if my updated answer still doesn't address the point.

Comment: Also fixed my bad that I used "threshold" which should be "throughput" for sure.

Comment: @JungtaekLim Thank you very much for your time to explain the details.

Comment: It's interesting that I was here around a year ago.